# what is the k-line-connected graph definition

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

What is the definition for k-line-connectedness of the graph ? I am in doubt whether it differs from usual k-vertex (edge) connectedness. I've encountered it in the paper titled "Np-complete problems on a 3-connected cubic planar graph and their applications" where it comes without definition. Unfortunately for me I couldn't get the definition from the context given in its authors' proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the proof of Lemma 1 in the paper, *3-line-connected* is the same as *3-edge-connected*; *line* is probably a translation from Japanese.

Comment: Unfortunately with 3-edge-connectedness Lemma 1 proof is wrong.

Comment: You can find an alternative proof here: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~mubayi/591/Spring2010/hw3sol.pdf.

Comment: This is OK now. Thanks. Let me wait a bit to get final check for this answer. :-)

Comment: After the second reading I get that this Japanese paper contains wrong proofs. That's sad. Not only for 3-connectedness = 3-edge-connectedness statement but also for main results.

Comment: For example, for completeness of VC when replacing the 1-disconnecting edges the situation could happen when the gadget is adjacent to at least two gadgets. In this case obtained graph is not cubic,